# AltBeacon Library - setBackgroundScanPeriod not working

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, beacon

I am detecting beacon by using [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html).

According to other Stackoverflow question answer below is the solution

```
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(60000l);
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(60000l);
beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
```

but in my case it is not working. I am not able to make variation on scanning period.

**Here is the code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    try {
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(60000l);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(60000l);
        beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();

        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId",
                Identifier.parse(Config.PROXIMITY_UUID), null, null));
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "minor:"+ beacons.iterator().next().getId3());
                }


            }
        });
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see that makes you say it is not working?  With the code shown, when the app is in the background, it should look for beacons for 60 seconds, report results, then stop looking for beacons for 60 seconds before starting up again.   When the app is in the foreground, scans should go on continually with results reported every 1.1 seconds.

Comment: i want to scan in every 60 seconds in foreground is it possible ?

Comment: OK, I think that clarifies what you are asking.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change scan periods in the foreground, you can use the equivalent methods to alter the foreground behavior:

```
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(60000l);
beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(60000l);
beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
```

Understand that what the above will do is make a scan happen for 60 seconds, then process the results of all beacons seen, then stop scanning for 60 seconds before starting the cycle over.  If you don't want to stop scanning every other minute, use code like this, which immediately starts a new scan cycle after the last one ends:

```
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(60000l);
beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0l);
beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
```